# Output all errors and warnings after PHP script finishes, instead of when they occur

Tags: php

I want my script to run to the end regardless of if there is any warning, notice or error during the time code running. I don't want these warnings/notices/errors to appear between the lines of output from my script.

Instead, I want all the error messages to be output under the rest of my script's output, *after* the script finishes executing.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you want code to execute even if it can't execute?  That's... interesting.

Answer (score -1):

```
ob_start();
// your code here
$reports = ob_get_clean();
// file_put_contents('reports.txt', $reports);
```